# Finding solution of $ \frac{2y}{x} = y' $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is what I was able to do:
$$ \frac{2y}{x} = \frac{dy}{dx} \implies (1) $$

$$ 2y\ dx = x\ dy \implies (2)  $$
$$ \frac{dx}{x} = \frac{dy}{2y} \implies (3) $$
$$ \frac{dx}{x} - \frac{dy}{2y} =  0 \implies (4) $$
$$ \ln(x) - \ln(y^\frac{1}{2}) =  c \implies (5) $$
$$ \ln\bigg(\frac{x}{y^{\frac{1}{2}}} \bigg)  =  c \implies (6) $$
$$ \frac{x}{y^{\frac{1}{2}}}  =  c \implies (7) $$
$$ \frac{x^2}{y}  =  c \implies (8) $$
$$ \frac{x^2}{c}  =  y \implies (9) $$
$$ x^2c^{-1}  =  y \implies (10) $$

Please I have two questions:

1. I want to know if **step (7)** can be written as
   $$ \frac{x}{y^{\frac{1}{2}}}  =  e^c $$
2. The final answer to the question was
   $$ cx^2  =  y $$ but I don't know why I had 
   $$ c^{-1}x^2  =  y \implies (10) $$

Comment: Line (5): the exponent should be in the parentheses since it applies to $y$, not to the output of the logarithm.

Comment: c is just a label for an arbitrary constant, so c 1/c, and $e^c$ are all arbitrary.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Thanks  for the clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To your first question:  You can write it that way and you must do something of that form.  The domain of the real logarithm is $(0,\infty)$, so you should restrict $x/\sqrt{y}$ to that interval.  Writing the right-hand side as $\mathrm{e}^c$ is one way to do so.

You your second question, the constant of integration in $\int x^{-1} \,\mathrm{d}x = \ln |x| + C$ does not represent a specific constant.  The expression "$\ln |x| + C$" represents the infinite collection of antiderivatives, differing pairwise by a constant offset.  In this way, your "$c$" is not representing a particular constant, it is indicating that you have a set of solutions differing by various choices of values of $c$.

This interpretation gives your "$c$" some very weird properties:

- $c+2 = c$, $c+\sqrt{2}= c$, $c - \ln 2 = c$: adding a constant to an arbitrary real constant yields an arbitrary real constant and every arbitrary real constant can be realized as such a sum.
- $c+c = c$: the sub of two arbitrary real constants is some arbitrary real constant and every arbitrary real constant can be realized as the sum of two arbitrary real constants.
- $c-c = c$: the difference of two arbitrary real constants is an arbitrary real constant and every arbitrary real constant can be realized as such a difference.
- $2c = c$: (I think you see where this is going...):
- $c^{-1}$: represents the collection of arbitrary nonzero real numbers, since $0$ is the only real number that is not the reciprocal of some other real number.
- But...  $c^2$ represents the collection of arbitrary nonnegative real numbers and
- $\mathrm{e}^c$ represents the collection of arbitrary positive real numbers.

So, in line (7), you should have the restriction "$c>0$".  Then in or after line (10), you can replace "$c^{-1}$" with "$c$", retaining the restriction "$c > 0$".

So what about $c<0$ and $c=0$ in the provided solution?  Line (6) prohibits both of these.  So should these be solutions?

- $c=0$: This gives the potential solution $y = 0x^2 = 0$.  Then $\frac{2y}{x} = 0$ and $y'=0$, so this *is* a solution.
- $c < 0$:  This gives the potential solution $y = -ax^2$ for a specific constant $a>0$.  Then $\frac{2y}{x} = -2ax$ and $y' = -2ax$.

So these *are* also solutions.  How do we detect them?  Get a general solution with a constrained constant of integration, then relax the constraint to see how many more solutions you find.  We essentially did this in the above.

Comment: so can we say c=0 is a solution and c < 0 is also a solution

Comment: This is a good/instructive answer (+1).

Comment: @EALehn : Perhaps you didn't read to the end...

Comment: @EricTowers I read it. Or It should rather be $ y = 0$ when $c$ is equal to $0$

Comment: @EALehn : "c=0:"..."y=0x2=0" ... "So these *are* also solutions. How do we detect them? ...".  The answer to your question is literally spelled out.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed write step 7 as $e^c$ on the right hand side. Another option would be to change the variable name i.e $a = e^c$. Your answer is actually the same, since the constant $c$ is arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

Some general remarks about your solution:

At step five, you need to include absolute value signs around the two logarithms. As the domain of $\log(x)$ is $x>0$, it is necessary to include the absolute value symbol. This step would read

$$\ln|x|−\ln\left|y^{1/2}\right|=c\tag{5}$$

then step six would read

$$\ln\left|\frac{x}{y^{1/2}}\right|=c\tag{6}$$

which would force $c>0$ since the logarithmic function is only defined when $x>0$.

At step seven, you could certainly change $c$ to $\large{e^{c_1}}$ as $c$ is an arbitrary positive constant. However, it isn't necessary to do this. Continuing from your solution at step $7$

$$\frac{x}{y^{1/2}}=c\tag{7}$$
$$\frac{x^2}{y}=c_1\tag{8}$$
$$\frac{x^2}{c_1}=y\tag{9}$$
$${c_2x^2}=y\tag{10}$$

where the values of $c,c_1,$ and $c_2$ are all different arbitrary positive constants. As $c_1>0$, we don't run into any problems when we divide by this constant. The cases for $c=0$ and $c<0$ are covered in Eric's instructive answer.